# Right place for ddots

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fourier

I've got a problem, when making a presentation with `beamer`. I want to use the `fourier` package for the fonts, and use the serif font in math mode.

So that's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
$\ddot{r}$
\end{document}
```

And the result doesn' look that nice (the dots are too much on the left):

[image: ddots with fourier]

Without the `fourier`-package, it looks much better:

[image]

Is there a possibility to solve this without negative whitespaces, like `\ddot{\!r}`?

Comment: maybe thats an suitable solution: `\newcommand*{\ddown}[1]{\,\ddot{\!#1}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the font theme `professionalfonts` to stop `beamer` making certain changes.  Note the final `s` - there seems to be a misprint in the current version of the `beamer` manual, I have reported the issue.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
$\ddot{r}$
\end{document}
```